# Extremal of functional $ I\left[ y(x) \right] = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} {\left((y')^2 - y^2 + 2xy\right)dy} $

Tags: calculus, integration, calculus-of-variations

I have the following functional:

$$ I\left[ y(x) \right] = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} {\left((y')^2 - y^2 + 2xy\right)dy} $$
subject to boundary conditions:

$$
\begin{align}
y(0) &= 0 \\
y\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right) &= 0
\end{align}
$$

Applying the Euler-Lagnrange's condition $ \left( f_y = \dfrac{\text{d}f_{y'}}{\text{dx}} \right) $; I proceed as follows after replacing $ dy $ with $ y' dx $:

$$
\begin{align}
f \equiv f(x, y, y') &= (y')^3 - y' y^2 + 2 x y y' \\
f_y &= -2 y y' + 2 x y' \\
f_{y'} &= 3(y')^2 - y^2 + 2xy \\
\text{and } \dfrac{\text{d}f_{y'}}{\text{dx}} &= 6 y' y'' - 2 y y' + 2 y + 2 x y' \tag{1} \\
\therefore 3 y' y'' + y &= 0 \tag{ Take $ v \equiv v(y) = \frac{dy}{dx} $} \\
3 v (v v') + y &= 0 \tag{ $ v' = \frac{dv}{dy} $ } \\
\implies 3 v^2 dv + y dy &= 0 \\
\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3 + \frac{y^2}{2} &= \frac{c^2}{2} \\
\sqrt[3]{2} \frac{dy}{dx} &= \left( c^2 - y^2 \right) ^{\frac{1}{3}}
\end{align}
$$

- Are the above steps correct?
- **How do I proceed now?**

[Wolfram shows](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%20y%27%20=%20%281%20-%20y%5E2%20%29%20%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%7D) the answer to be some hypergeometric form; which I have no idea about.

Comment: Is your functional really an integral over $y$ instead of $x$?

Comment: @achillehui [yep](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uf8tz.png)

Comment: In the line $3v(vv') + y = 0$, you should mention $v'$ is $\frac{dv}{dy}$. Otherwise, people may mistaken it as $\frac{dv}{dx}$. The last line should be $\color{red}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\frac{dy}{dx} = (c^2-y^2)^{1/3}$. Aside from these, the other steps look fine to me.